# how to make my shortcut in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin, shortcut

I want to use a shortcut to move the cursor to the next line or previous line.
I can't find this Command in Preferences->General->Keys.

Are there any plugins that can do this? Or do I have to develop my own plugin to for that? If I have to develop it, which extension point should I use?

Comment: try that key which shows an upward/downward pointing arrow on your keyboard ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your question correctly then you should be able to set the Eclipse Key Mappings for Up Arrow and Down Arrow keys.

Search for "Line Up" and you will see

```
Line Up
Scroll Line Up
Select Line Up
```

These should already be mapped to Up/Down Arrow and Shift Up/Down Arrow, but if not (eclipse does mess up keyboard mappings from time to time) you can add them back or set them the way you want.